# How to avoid auto unix timestamp convert in EXCEL

Tags: excel, excel-formula, timestamp

I really need your help

I want to add an "," and 2 ' in my timestamp in excel. (to at the end, import my csv into sql)As you can see in the picture

[image: 1]

But Excel auto convert my timestamp into UNIX timestamp.
Do you have an idea to avoid that?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Please edit your original post to show the starting text and expected output, (not in an image) as well as how you are adding the ,2 to the end.  Also include the datatype of the columns.  Thank you.

Comment: That number  is actually the Excel DateTime serial number.  You can use the [Text](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/text-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c) function to format it as you want, and concatenate the extra characters as you wish